# How to teach zsh when not do autocorrect?

Tags: zsh, autocorrection

I love the autocorrection feature of ZSH, but sometimes it gets in the way:

- If I have a `cli` directory, it will be suggested when I try to run `npm run ci`.
- When running the Docker command `docker run -v /some/dir:/var/www` it will try to autocorrect to `/some/dir/var/www`
- ... and many more

Now I **don't** want to turn off autocorrection or prefix the command with `nocorrect`. What I would like is more of a "learning" autocorrection that wraps around the normal suggestions, counts how many times I said "no" to a suggestion and does not suggest it any more if I've said "no" for 3 times. I something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You can use [`$CORRECT_IGNORE`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-CORRECT_005fIGNORE) and [`$CORRECT_IGNORE_FILE`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-CORRECT_005fIGNORE_005fFILE) to tell Zsh to not suggest certain *corrections,* but you cannot tell Zsh to not correct certain inputs. So, there wouldn't even be a point in trying to write a function that would collect all words that should not be corrected, because there's no of way of communicating this info to Zsh.

You are probably better off using just `setopt CORRECT`, which corrects misspelled commands only, and not `setopt CORRECT_ALL`, which attempts to correct *all* words on the line. You can use `unsetopt CORRECT_ALL` to unset it, if necessary.

Another alternative would be to use [the `zsh-hist` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-hist), which lets you edit your last command line by pressing <kbd>undo</kbd> or any previous line from your history with the `hist` command. This might be a more reliable way of fixing typos.